# Getting a inforworks ICM pyswmm export to run

Tags: pyswmm

I am working with an .inp export form inforworks ICM and is trying to get the model running using pyswmm. At the moment the python kernel crashes every time I try to load the .inp file. I working my way through this but wondering if anyone in the community has experience of getting this to work ?

I have had to re-parse the .inp export to get it to load using swmmio and swmm-api, but still experiencing problems using PySWMM.swmm_open, the python kernel crashes.